# Linearize non-linear model considering a partial set of states in Matlab\Simulink

Tags: matlab, controls, simulink, states, linearization

I've a non-linear model with 9 states. For the linearization procedure, it considers 8 states because one state is not visible from a point of view of linearization, in base of assumptions .
My question is (and hope someone helps me): how to do in order to linearize this model neglecting that particolar state? Next, once I've implemented the control logic on linearized model, I have to only feedback the states used for the linearization and not consider the neglected state??
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Which function are you using, hopefully LINEARIZE, not LINMOD?

In linearize, the default answer will be minimal, i.e. eliminating those states that do not contribute to the linearization result (e.g. states coming from blocks that are not in the linearization path). If you like to obtain full answer with all states (possibly non-minimal), you can turn that option off.

See BlockReduction option in the page: http://www.mathworks.com/help/slcontrol/ug/linearizeoptions.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Really, I'm using the Linear Analisys Tool, that in turn it uses LINEARIZE procedure but I can't linearize my model...